# how to combine result of two queries in one resultset

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'rating'
it has two fields 'cab_id' and 'rating' which stores id for cabs and its rating as either 1 or 0. 
I want to retrieve values as up or down as sum of counts as 1 or 0. 
I used two queries as

```
      (SELECT count(rating) as up FROM 

     `rating` WHERE cab_id=101 and rating=1 )
```

and

```
     (SELECT count(rating) as down FROM 

     `rating` WHERE cab_id=101 and rating=0 )
```

I want to retrieve in the format of one result .

```
         ----------
      up          down

         ----------


       1             2         


        ----------
```

Please lend a help here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(rating=1,1,0)) up,
    SUM(IF(rating=0,1,0)) down
FROM rating
WHERE cab_id=101
```